# Trying to allocate maximum possible memory to process

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

This is on Windows XP and application is being developed in C++ (VS2010).

I want my application to go on allocating memory till it reaches its limits without any problems. But if it allocates whole 2GB (max limit on 32-bit Windows), it overwrites space for stack and eventually it crashes. How can this be avoided? (Btw, I am using `malloc` and `new` for memory allocation)

1. Out of "Private Bytes", "Virtual Bytes" and "Working Set", I believe I should monitor "Virtual Bytes". But I am not completely sure on this. (Is it "Virtual Bytes" or "Private Bytes" when touches 2GB we can be certain that we touched the limit?)
2. If it is "Virtual Bytes" I have to monitor, I am not sure which field of `_PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` reflects virtual bytes
3. To keep application running safe and smooth, how much memory I should keep aside? (Is it just *Stack size = Number of threads x Stack size per thread* or there is something more than that)

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: @Victor: Just to utilize maximum possible memory...?

Comment: Check malloc return value (and according to compilation settings also new return value). NULL (or exception) are there for that reason. You can't even check free memory only because you'll need contiguous space. Calculation isn't so straight because of various overheads.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti: With that approach it overruns stack

Comment: You shouldn't keep memory aside. You should allocate memory as needed, and watch for and handle memory allocation error (malloc returns NULL on memory error).

Comment: Are we sure don't have to worry about stack size or I am missing something here ? I am getting mad after I see my application goes unstable if I just go on allocating (by just checking for NULL)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that it's not your application code that's overwriting your stack when malloc starts failing?  Or, perhaps a library you're using?

Comment: If allocation fails it won't overwrite stack...you'll just get NULL (and that may corrupt application or trigger an access violation). Stack Overflow is probably caused by something else (for example...dynamic stack will fail to grow-up when there isn't a contiguous block of free memory).

Answer (score 0):

The program manager will keep aside space for your stack and other data. You can call malloc and new until they will return 0 (NULL). I think that Working Set is the variable you need to monitor.

Comment: With 2GB allocation, I observed my application becomes unstable and gives "stack overflow" errors. Also "Working Set" is allocation committed to physical RAM and could be more already allocated memory which might have paged to disk.

Comment: Can you post your sourcecode so that i can test it on my machine ?

Comment: @GeoAoe, Sorry for delayed reply. Its too big to post. I am experimenting with it. I guess the problem is something else and results in 'stack overflow' error. Additionally, around 2GB memory consumption, starting new thread also gives error `R6016 - not enough space for thread data`

Answer (score 0):

You can access up to 3Gb by modifying your boot.ini file

```
[boot loader]
timeout=5
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS 
[operating systems] 
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect /3GB
```

Then you need to modify your executable using editbin (comes with express version as well)

```
editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE xxx.exe
```

This works for me.  If this doesn't work then the optional header is missing.  I don't know how you force the header to be there.

If you have lots of time - this is the long story http://www.dansdata.com/askdan00015.htm

Comment: It's his application so he may want to use /LARGEADDRESSAWARE directly as linker option.